# Get City, State, Zip Code from Longitude & Latitude in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to get city, state, zip code of a user from longitude & latitude. I followed some tutorials from stackoverflow about google maps **Reverse geocoding API**, But It is returning sometime the array which has 2 to 3 length & something the length is 6 to 8. So i am not able to get exact in which index i can find the city,state & zip. Below is my code to get longitude & latitude of user.

```
  var longitude,latitude;

  if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  } 
  function showPosition(position) {
   longitude = position.coords.longitude;
   latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I had good experience just taking the first result

Comment: you should check for reverse  geocoding

Comment: Hey Readers, Please Read My Question Carefully Before Downvoating. I know it can be possible through Geocoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You are Right,

You will get length of array of random numbers which is based on address. **To get the country, state, city & zipcode,** You will have to choose first array in the results array and in that choose address_components array, Here in this array, Last index of array is **zipcode**, Second last index of array is **country**, third last index of array is **state** & fourth last index of array is your **city**. Please have a look at the below image to understand structure of arrays.

**Note:** I tested it in india, Not sure about any other country.

[image: attached image]

**Thanks.**

Comment: You did not tell how to get this result?